# Unable to execute JAR file

Tags: java, mysql

I'm learning Java and I have created my first Java project, which is just a demo application of UPI. My project run perfectly inside IDE (using Netbeans IDE), but when I create the JAR file and try to execute it, it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at swift.upi.LoginUI.initComponents(LoginUI.java:350)
    at swift.upi.LoginUI.<init>(LoginUI.java:27)
    at swift.upi.Welcome.nextBtnMouseClicked(Welcome.java:133)
    at swift.upi.Welcome.access$000(Welcome.java:14)
    at swift.upi.Welcome$1.mouseClicked(Welcome.java:67)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error occurs when I try to perform any event such as mouse click event.
Because of this, I'm only able to run my project inside IDE.
Try to explain the problem and solution in a simple and easy way.
I'm giving the link to my project for convenience, found 
[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qat_WY7KIakyyZjhI4goUJCcYx0w7rQ7).

Thank you.

Comment: based on `javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>` it is not finding the image given in the statement in/at `swift.upi.LoginUI.initComponents(LoginUI.java:350)`

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by the comment by Carlos, the problem is with finding the icon/image referred in line 350 of `LoginUI.java`.

Comparing your zipped project content with the code of the class I *guess* the problem might be with the file name and its case.

- code says `/swift/upi/Name logo.jpg`
- while the directory contains a file called `Name Logo.jpg`

Try changing the `l` to `L`.
Also - I'd suggest you avoid space characters in the file names.